# iphone ARC - how to set an object to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have some logic that test if an object is nil or not, how can I set it to nil?

Like:

```
// in some method
if (true){
 [self myObj] = [[myObj alloc]init];
} else{
 [self myObject] = nil; //??? How to do this with Automatic Ref. Counting
}

// elsewhere
if([self myObj]){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Try:

```
self.myObject=nil;
//or
[self setMyObject:nil];
```

Also, make sure that myObject is a property in your class, otherwise using self won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is incorrect.

You need to use properties and assign values to them, like `[self setMyObject:nil];` or `[self setMyObj:[[myObj alloc] init]];`.

Answer (score 2):

`[self myObj]` is not assignable, as it is not a lvalue. To fix this, either reference the underlying variable, e.g. `self->myObj`,  or use `[self setMyObj:]` if you are using properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a getter as a setter. That isn't going to work. It should be

```
[self setMyObj:[myObj alloc]init]];
```

And

```
[self setMyObj:nil];
```

Assuming you have implemented the setters. Under ARC you don't really need to if you are just accessing an ivar - you can access it directly and the reference counting will be done for you:

```
myObj = [MyObj alloc] init];
```

And

```
myObj = nil;
```

Will set and remove everything for you.